# Do we need APIs to just access databases?

Tags: rest, api, web-applications, web-api

At work, we have a Web application, which makes queries to databases, and I’m asked to determine if using Web APIs could be an added value.

Personally, I’m not convinced it is.

I know Web APIs are tailored to let different systems speak a “common language”, but having one to just access databases seems overkill to me. Yes, I can edit, update and publish the API independently from the client application, but that seems to be the only good factor to me. The Web API would be stored in an on-premise server, so Cloud’s typical scalability, elasticity, etc. aren’t things to consider.

I’m talking about HTTP RESTful APIs. We have an ASP.NET MVC Web application (so, server-rendered) querying databases. Currently, the code to call the databases in embedded in the source code of the ASP.NET application.

Can I have your opinion?

Comment: How _exactly_ are you proposing to control access to your database if you're not going through an API?

Comment: Currently, the Web application (which I inherited) has queries in the code, used with EF.

Comment: That's not access control.

Comment: So, what you mean? We go with connections strings that use a specific user.

Comment: If your using ef, do you mean that you have a server rendered page? By Web application do you mean a js+html frontend or a c# application that outputs html?

Comment: @user1937198 an ASP.NET MVC application, so, yes, server-rendered.

Comment: WebApi are for Js frameworks, and EntityFramework (if that's it) IS an API. an api is not necessarily a webapi! It seem overkill to combine both, except if you need decoupling between applications.

Comment: @PineCode are you talking separate HTTP API vs API embedded in your existing web app, or HTTP API vs clients directly querying your DB?

Comment: Or a server-rendered web application vs a rich client app using APIs? This lacks clarity.

Comment: How does the web application access the database without using an API?

Comment: @JörgWMittag it can be server-side rendered, the client can use something else than an HTTP API to communicate with the server, etc. Also, the term "API" is questionable if, say, you just have GET and POST endpoints that only your UI client uses and tailor-made for it.

Comment: @guillaume31: If it is server-side rendered, then how does the server access the database without using an API?

Comment: @JörgWMittag OP means "HTTP API" (and yes, the term API has been deviated from its original meaning).

Comment: "but having one to just access databases seems overkill to me" it isn't. For you see, [APIs are about policy](https://acko.net/blog/apis-are-about-policy/), and databases only give you very coarse-grained ways to control and implement policy. I'm struggling to think of a non-trivial CRUD app I've built in the last 10 years we're e.g. postgres' access controls were sufficient to the task. Not to mention the security risk of having not hard-coded queries run against your db....

Answer (score 4):

If your application is purely a server side rendered application with no need to integrate with external systems,  then a http api will add no value. You should still have an api, the internal model that your controllers call into to generate your views, but there is no need to expose it to the outside world.

There are however two capabilities exposing that model as an api would unlock. Firstly it would enable you to query new data from the client using javascript to update part of a page without a complete refresh. Secondly, a documented published api would all your clients to build automated integrations with external systems.

Comment: Yes. Worth noting that having the additional capabilities is not always a good thing - having the capabilities implies an intent and commitment to maintaining them, and maintaining them can have a significant cost, in terms of work required as the system changes and barriers created to changing the system in future. OP should not create capabilities unless they are valuable enough make bearing these costs worth it.

Comment: yes, the real difference will be enabling the switch to a SPA style front end. Not in adding an extra layer to your existing backend

Comment: Yes, with SPAs, APIs are necessay.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, the code to call the databases in embedded in the source code of the ASP.NET application.

If the ASP.NET application is the only application that uses the database, and that's not likely to change, then keeping the database query code embedded in the ASP.NET code is very likely the simplest and therefore best thing to do.

You may want to segregate the database code from other code within that application, maybe with a pattern like [repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) if you haven't already done it, but there's no real advantage, and some big disadvantages, to creating a separate application just to be an HTTP API over the database.

Keeping it all together in one repository and one deployment unit allows much easier evolution of the structure and semantics of the database over time, and lets you run tests as part of continuous integration to check that your application works with your database structure.

If you build an API around the database, then it will either be very general, in which case it doesn't really give you any advantage over connecting to the database directly, or it will be specific to the data used by your application, in which case whenever that changes you will need to make changes in both the API application and the application application, which will slow you down and discourage you from working to improve the internal design.